# How to disable TextButton when text field is empty?

Tags: flutter, dart

I implemented a value listener but it is not working.

```dart
ValueListenableBuilder<TextEditingValue>(
  valueListenable: passwordcontroller,
  builder: (context, value, child) {
    return Center(
      child: TextButton(
        onPressed: value.text.isEmpty ? null : null,
        child: const Text(
          "Sign In",
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 17,
              fontFamily: "San Francisco Bold",
              color: Colors.blue,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, the issue is that you are overriding the style. Try changing your `TextStyle`.`color` to:

```
color: value.text.isEmpty ? null : Colors.blue,
```

Then, the `TextButton` will style as you'd expect, using the app's theme